# Index-wise (byte-wise?) locking/atomic addition into std::vector or Eigen::Array?

Tags: c++, multithreading, eigen

I need to calculate and then add values to an Eigen::ArrayXd (array of doubles). Because this operation takes a long time, I have split this work amongst threads. Due to the nature of the problem, most of the time threads will be adding to different indices than each other. (and generally the problem is relatively sparse compared to the overall array)

However, this raises the obvious problem of multiple threads trying to add to the same index simultaneously.

There are 2 ways I know of to deal with this:

- Give each thread its own copy of the final Eigen array, and sum them
  together. This is good for performance, but can use an incredibly
  large amount of memory for my problem. (Several gigabytes is very possible)
- Give each thread a more compact structure (like a
  std::unordered_map<int, double>) containing just the indices it
  operated on. This is uses far less memory, but the overhead of the
  final addition is so large it ends up almost completely nullifying
  the multi-threaded improvement.

An example of the first approach is here:

```
  unsigned numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

  std::vector<Eigen::ArrayXd> threadData( numThreads );
  std::vector<std::thread> threads( numThreads );

  // This spools up new threads to perform the calculation
  if ( numThreads == 1 ) {
    threadData[0] = Eigen::ArrayXd::Zero( solutionArray.size() );
    calculateThread( 0, 1, threadData[0] );

    solutionArray += threadData[0];
  } else {
    // Start the threads
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ ) {
      threadData[i] = Eigen::ArrayXd::Zero( solutionArray.size() );
      threads[i] = std::thread( &My_class::calculate,
        this,
        i,
        numThreads,
        std::ref( threadData[i] ) );
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ ) {
      threads[i].join();
      const Eigen::ArrayXd &threadSol = threadData[i];

      // Add this thread's results into the final solution array
      solutionArray += threadSol;
    }
  }
```

Neither of these are ideal. Is there some way to byte-wise lock a std::vector or Eigen::ArrayXd so that multiple threads can access and add to the array without a large memory overhead or slow combination step? That way the only wasted time is whenever they do hit the same index, which is fairly rare.

I ask about std::vector since it's relatively trivial to just convert one into an Eigen array, so if there is no Eigen equivalent I can do that instead.

Comment: Have you considered atomic updates of elements? C++20 should provide this via `std::atomic_ref`. OpenMP can do this as well with `#pragma omp atomic update`. Note that, for instance, x86/x64 does not support floating-point atomic operations, but they may be accomplished with moving data to generic registers and compare-exchange. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/naf1oaroa.

Comment: @DanielLangr Interesting. So I could pass the position of an individual index of that array into that atomic update method? I guess that makes sense, at the low level there is no difference between a double in an array and one not in an array. I will give that a try and report back. Thank you as well for providing the OMP version, as I'm not positive if we're on C++17 or 20.

Comment: AFAIK OpenMP atomics can only be applied in some specific cases: typically a variable of a primitive type (eg. int, double, a pointer) or a memory reference (eg. reference, array item), but they certainly does not work directly with Eigen's ArrayXd. You certainly need to extract the raw pointer to perform atomic operations (be careful about strides).

Comment: @DanielLangr Just wanted to report back the C++20 option worked fantastic, providing even a speedup over the Eigen arrays since there was no need to allocate large sums of memory repeatedly. If you want to turn it into an answer I'll gladly mark it as complete.

Comment: You said your per-thread arrays are sparse. How sparse? You could use Eigen's sparse matrix module for the per-thread data, then do pairwise matrix additions until you get the final result.

Comment: If you decide to use atomics, note that they are slow (ballpark 1 per 20 cycles). So interleave them with the actual computation to keep the thread busy in the mean time. If you don't have ```atomic_ref```, a ```reinterpret_cast<atomic<double>*>(&double)``` will work in practice. It's not standard-conforming but it should work on mainstream compilers for x86, AArch64 etc.

Comment: Another point to complete what Homer512 said: the use of atomics generally prevent the auto-vectorisation of loops by compilers. This may or may not be a problem regarding your computation (ie. whether the loops are SIMD-friendly or not). SIMD instruction can strongly speed up numerical codes (eg. AVX can compute 4 double-precision numbers at once and AVX-512 reach even 8 at once). Moreover, you should care about the consistency model as the default one prevent the reordering of the read/write instructions causing stall and an even slower execution.